# Adding strings to a RichTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I currently have a function that will set a value to a RichTextBox, although how could you "add" a value or a new line to it, rather than overwriting existing data in the RichTextBox?

```
richTextBox2.Text = DateTime.Today + " Hello";
```

Comment: James, I recommend you to use a single OpenId to log in, so you will be [the same user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/816110/james-buttler) as usually

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
richTextBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Today + " Hello");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
richTextBox2.AppendText(String.Format("{0} the date is {1}{2}", "Hello", DateTime.Today, Environment.NewLine));
```

Please don't use +

Comment: Why no "+"? Just for readability? Or is there an other reason?

Comment: @JosuaSchmid strings are immutable. Using + to chain n of them (especially for big strings and/or many catenations) creates n-1 strings in memory one bigger than the last one, resulting in a (temporary) waste of memory and a lot of computing overhead. This is why using String.Format() and the StringBuilder-Class is prefered in favor of +

Answer (score 4):

```
richTextBox2.Document.Blocks.Clear();
richTextBox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("string")));
```

Comment: The user asked for winforms not for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this as a simple log-to-screen kinda thing to inform user of stuff going on in the background or to acknowledge various actions.

Add a RichTextBox on the form, here I call it "rtbLog"

Then call the below and add your message and any optional formatting you want.  So for example:

```
DoWriteToLog("Hey, welcome!", true, Color.Green)


public void DoWriteToLog(string strLogMessage, bool blnHighlighted = false, Color myFontColor = default(Color), bool blnNewLine = true)
        {
            string dtStamp = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "] ";
            if (blnNewLine)
                strLogMessage = dtStamp + strLogMessage + Environment.NewLine;
            if (blnHighlighted)
            {                
                rtbLog.SelectionColor = myFontColor;             // Optional font color passed to method
                if (strLogMessage.ToLower().Contains("help"))       // IF there is 'help' in the message, highlight it blue
                    rtbLog.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                rtbLog.SelectionFont = new Font("Cambria", 10F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                rtbLog.AppendText(strLogMessage);                
            }
            else            
                rtbLog.AppendText(strLogMessage);
            rtbLog.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

The above DoWriteToLog statement will write "Hey, welcome!" to the RichTextBox in bold Green font.  It adds a timestamp to each line entered as well, but you can avoid that by turning off blnNewLine.  Of course it's specific to my use, but you can modify it to suit yours.

I also have a help 'detector' in there so if I am putting a help message on the screen it highlights it a specific color, you can comment/delete those two lines as needed.

Note the only required parameter, of course, is the message.  This way, since I use this a lot, I don't have to add all the parameters every time thus, saving lots of typing :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
richTextBox2.Text = "Something " + richTextBox2.Text + " and something"
```

Comment: @abatishchev There is more than one function adding text to this, hence I don't think your solution would work

Comment: This is going to be horribly inefficient when there is a lot of text in the control

Comment: @David: Nothing said in the answer about a lot of text

Comment: reading the entire contents of the control just to add another line of text is very inefficient. Why go out of your way to write inefficient code?

Comment: @David: Does `RichTextBox.Text` property read entire control content rather than holds it into a variable? I didn't knew that.

Comment: It's just a wrapper around the Windows control I expect and the Windows control holds the text. The implementation of the Text getter will send a message to the control to retrieve the entire text, I'd guess.