# richTextBox - add text and table

Tags: c#, richtextbox

i want to add formatted text and table to a richTextBox.

For this I use these codes:

Text:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Maiandra GD", 30, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox1.SelectionIndent = 0;
richTextBox1.AppendText("text text text");
```

And the table:

```
StringBuilder tableRtf = new StringBuilder();

tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}");
for (int j = 0; j <5; j++)
{
    tableRtf.Append(@"\trowd");
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx2500" + "  ghhghgjghjghjhggjh");
    tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl\cell");
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx10000\intbl\cel");
    tableRtf.Append("   " + "sdfsdfs" + @"\intbl\clmrg\cell\row");
}

tableRtf.Append(@"\pard");
tableRtf.Append(@"}");
richTextBox1.Rtf=tableRtf.ToString();
```

But the

```
richTextBox1.Rtf=tableRtf.ToString();
```

kills the previous contents.

How can I make compatible them?

---

It is not a duplicate because I want two thing:

1) add formatted text to richTextBox this way:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Maiandra GD", 30, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox1.AppendText("text text text");
```

It is well readable and I can modify easily.

2) And I want to add tables.

So the structure:

text text text text text 
text text text text text

|TABLE|

text text text text text
text text text text text
text text text text text

|TABLE|

etc.

But I don't know how can I apply tables without losing previous contents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding strings to a RichTextBox in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485156/adding-strings-to-a-richtextbox-in-c-sharp)

Comment: do you want to do richTextBox1.Rtf=tableRtf.Rtf; ?
calling .ToString will just give you a system string, which obviously doesn't hold any formatting.

Comment: @Joe_DM But the formatting is obviously done in the string

Comment: `richTextBox1.Rtf+=something` or add `richTextBox1.Rtf` to `tableRtf ` before.

Comment: Sorry, Thought Op was trying to get text out of the richtextbox. I can see he is trying to append text.
Doesn't `RichTextBox` have an `AppendText` method directly?
edit: I clicked on t he duplicate question listed and can see it does and that this is most likely a duplicate as suggested.

Comment: @Joe_DM AppendText is not working with my table. The table disappears and will be simple text. ;}}\trowd\cellx2500  ghhghgjghjghjhggjh\intbl\cell\

Comment: @Sinatr It was my first idea: `richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf+ tableRtf.ToString();` But it does not work, the table does not show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is to dissect the rtf codes into the headers and the bodies.

The table body starts with the loop and keeping the `\par` is surely a good idea.

But you must neither replace the old text nor simply append the body to the end.

Instead you need to insert it **before the last curly**! This is because that last curly **marks the end of the whole rtf code** and anything after it will be ignored!

This was simple.

For a full solution you also will want to combine the headers.

This is a lot more work and writing it all out would go beyond an SO answer.

But the basic principle is simple:

You need to understand the things your table header adds to the things already in the primal header.

The most common things are a`font table` and a `color table`.

So if you want to use one or more different fonts in the appended table you need to do this:

- add them to the font table with a new font index, e.g. as `\f1\fnil Consolas;` after the previous semicolon.
- use it by changing the loop to include the new font right after the first `\intbl` table-paragraph-formatting control word:  `\intbl\f2\fs24  ghhghgjghjghjhggjh`.
- repeat as needed if you want to use different fonts in the table.
- add a `cfN`font color selector, if you want to.

The same idea will also work for the color table. It doesn't have a explicit indexing, so order matters; all colors are appended, each with a semicolon at the end:

```
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;\red25\green0\blue220;}
```

..adds a blue color to the red from the formatted text.

You see, this is work and takes some effort and preparations.

You can find the full rtf specs here.

Here is a screenshot of playing a little with the rtf..:

[image]

Note that the parts of table header was created by the control; you may want to use a dummy control for this or maybe you can figure out which parts you need and which are not necessary..

**Update:** Here is a 'appending rtf for dummies' version:

```
tableRtf.Append(@"{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier;}}");
for (int j = 0; j <5; j++)
{
    tableRtf.Append(@"\trowd");
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx2500" + "  ghhghgjghjghjhggjh");
    tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl\cell");
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx10000\intbl\cel");
    tableRtf.Append("   " + "sdfsdfs" + @"\intbl\clmrg\cell\row");
}

tableRtf.Append(@"\pard");
tableRtf.Append(@"}");

string rtf1 = richTextBox1.Rtf.Trim().TrimEnd('}');
string rtf2 = tableRtf.ToString();
richTextBox1.Rtf  = rtf1 + rtf2;
```

Note that the font table inserted before the table body does work! But make sure not to add the rtf-start tag!!

[image]

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you for your time and your very detailed answer!