# Creating a Table in a RichTextBox C# from Data in my SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, richtextbox

I have done some research about richtextboxes and how to add a table to them. I do not, however, understand how to insert data from my SQL database into this table, I was able to add the needed data to a richtextbox for a preview before sending the text in an email. I tried the above mentioned with some simple code making the output appending the text but this is not sufficient as a large amount of data will be sent via email and makes it hard to read.

Please see my code below (Keep in mind I am very new to the programming world)

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.1.201;Initial Catalog=JOSKEN;User ID=Admin;Password=Josken123!";
        connection.Open();

        //Reads Information from Database in terms of Job number

        //Variables
        int jobNumber;
        int itemNumber;
        string Qty;
        string itemMake;
        string itemModel;
        string itemSerial;
        string itemType;
        string specs;
        string fault;
        string Assessor;
        string replacementQuote;
        string replacementPrice;
        string totalPrice;
        itemMake = "";
        itemNumber = 0;
        itemType = "";
        itemModel = "";
        itemSerial = "";
        specs = "";
        jobNumber = 0;
        fault = "";
        replacementPrice = "";
        replacementQuote = "";
        totalPrice = "";

        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand();
        Cmd.Connection = connection;
        string Query = "Select * from Insurance_Items where Job_Number = '" + Convert.ToInt32(metroTxtJobNumberInternalReport.Text) + "'";
        Cmd.CommandText = Query;
        SqlDataReader reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int n = 1; n <= Convert.ToInt32(metroLblItemNoInternalReport.Text); n++) 
            {
                jobNumber = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Job_Number"]);
                itemNumber = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Item_Number"]);
                Qty = Convert.ToString(reader["Item_Qty"]);
                itemMake = Convert.ToString(reader["Item_Make"]);
                itemModel = Convert.ToString(reader["Item_Model"]);
                itemSerial = Convert.ToString(reader["Item_SerialNumber"]);
                itemType = Convert.ToString(reader["Item_Type"]);
                specs = Convert.ToString(reader["Item_Specs"]);
                fault = Convert.ToString(reader["Item_Fault"]);
                Assessor = Convert.ToString(reader["Assessor_Name"]);
                replacementQuote = Convert.ToString(reader["Replacement_Quote"]);
                replacementPrice = Convert.ToString(reader["Replacement_Price"]);
                totalPrice = Convert.ToString(reader["Total_Price"]);



            }



            string itemText = Environment.NewLine + "Item Make: " + itemMake + " " + itemType + Environment.NewLine + "Model: "
                    + itemModel + Environment.NewLine + "S/N: " + itemSerial
                    + Environment.NewLine + "Specs: " + Environment.NewLine + specs + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Assessment: " + fault + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine 
                    + "Replacement Quote: " + Environment.NewLine + replacementQuote + Environment.NewLine + "Replacement Price: R" + replacementPrice + Environment.NewLine + "Total Price: R" + totalPrice 
                    + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

            RedInternalReport.AppendText(itemText);
            string emailsubject = metrolblClientNameInternalReport.Text + " " + metrolblClaimNumberInternalReport.Text + " " + " | " + " Job Number: " + jobNumber + " | ";
            metroTxtSubjectInternalReport.Text = emailsubject;
            RedInternalReport.AppendText("=======================================================================================================");

        }

        connection.Close();
```

See below screenshot of the output:

[Output of Above Code when sent in email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqmHX.png)

I would like to output the data into 4 Columns and the number of rows should increase in terms of the number of items I am adding as defined in the metroLblItemNoInternalReport.Text

I would like to add itemMake, itemMode and itemSerial to the first column.
I would like to add specs to the second column
I would like to add fault to the third column
Finally, I would like to add replacementPrice, replacementQuote and totalPrice to the fourth and final column.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated

Comment: _I have done some research about richtextboxes and how to add a table to them._ Um, that is not so simple if I [remember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104890/richtextbox-add-text-and-table/45106691?r=SearchResults&s=1|63.2187#45106691) correctly. How did you do it?? Inserting the data sounds comparatively easy imo..

Comment: You really need parametrise your statements; you should never be injecting a parameter into your SQL.

Comment: @Larnu I know, I will clean up my code and write the SQL commands in the correct manner as soon as I have a program that can be used. At the moment It can not be used what it is intended for.

Comment: Why write vulnerable code in the first place though? Just write secure code at the start; it'll save you time too as you don't have to go through your entire application afterwards and fix **all** your injection issues. There's never a "good" excuse to not parametrise; they are all bad. "This is homework", or "this is test/development work" is not a reason to write bad code.

Comment: @Larnu I only learned how to code SQL commands in a saver manner a while ago and I will do so in the future. But for now, I just need to figure out how to solve my current problem of writing data into a Table in a richtextbox. Thank you for your honest criticism.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better to display your final result in an image. I hope this is what you want.

```
int jobNumber = 0;
int itemNumber = 0;
string Qty = "Qty";
string itemMake = "itemMake";
string itemModel = "itemModel";
string itemSerial = "itemSerial";
string itemType = "itemType";
string specs = "specs";
string fault = "fault";
string Assessor = "Assessor";
string replacementQuote = "replacementQuote";
string replacementPrice = "replacementPrice";
string totalPrice = "totalPrice";

int maxLen = itemMake.Length;
if (itemModel.Length > maxLen) maxLen = itemModel.Length;
if (itemSerial.Length > maxLen) maxLen = itemSerial.Length;
if (itemType.Length > maxLen) maxLen = itemType.Length;
if (specs.Length > maxLen) maxLen = specs.Length;
if (fault.Length > maxLen) maxLen = fault.Length;
if (replacementQuote.Length > maxLen) maxLen = replacementQuote.Length;
if (replacementPrice.Length > maxLen) maxLen = replacementPrice.Length;
if (totalPrice.Length > maxLen) maxLen = totalPrice.Length;

string formatter = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    formatter += $"{"{"}{i},{-maxLen}{"}"}";
}

// Use for loop to make rows
string formattedText = string.Format(formatter, itemMake, specs, fault, replacementPrice) +
    Environment.NewLine +
    string.Format(formatter, itemModel, "", "", replacementQuote) +
    Environment.NewLine +
    string.Format(formatter, itemSerial, "", "", totalPrice);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Is there a way to wrap the text for each column?